# Single youtube API to get total number of videos and and total number of subscribers on my channel

Tags: api, youtube-api

I tried Analytics and Reporting APIs separately. And there are questions and answers which deals with them separately. But I want to know is there any single one shot API which gives both? The total number of videos means all the videos irrespective of the playlists. I'm doing this with ReactJS for my own portfolio website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research on this. I couldn't find a full fledged api with documentation but you can use this:

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=statistics&id=your-channel-id&key=your-api-key

Make sure you've that api enabled. I'm using `Youtube Analytics`.